# Why is this button not aligning properly in html?

Tags: html, web

I have the following html snippet for a submit button:

```
<input style="height: 30px; width: 120px" type="submit" align="right" name="" value="Submit">
```

but it is not aligning to the right at all (or middle which is what I want). The align tag doesnt seem to be doing anything why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `align` **attribute** for the [`input` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element). You should use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) before wondering why markup doesn't work as you expect.

Use [CSS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#CSS) for presentation.

You probably want to use either [`text-align`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-align) on the parent element or [`float`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float)

Comment: float: right works but I can't get centered even if i do middle, MIDDLE, or center

Comment: The page I linked to lists the values that `float` accepts. None of middle, MIDDLE, or center are among them. Use `text-align` if you want to centre inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `align` attribute of HTML has been deprecated ages ago. As a good practice all the styling should be done by CSS and not HTML, like:

```
<input style="height: 30px; width: 120px; float: right" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
```

even a better practice - avoid inline CSS

```
<style>
input[type=submit] { height: 30px; width: 120px; float: right; }
</style>

<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: float: right works, it sends the button to the right, but despite trying center, middle, and MIDDLE i cant get it to be centered, am i missing yet another keyword?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uH2pJ/ to center it use the `margin: 0 auto` trick, but for that you have to make your button a block element